# dart2js Polymer Dart Sample ClickCounter App is OK in Firefox, fails in Chrome

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart2js

I am trying out a Polymer Dart App under Cordova. So I started with the Dart Editor Sample App.

I use a recent version of Polymer so I had to edit the sample code. Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: cortst
description: Cordova Test Application
dependencies:
 polymer: '>=0.15.1+3 <0.16.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/cortst.html
```

And here is the combined HTML and Dart. I think the initialization uses the new/approved technique:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample App</title>

    <link rel="import"     href="clickcounter.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cortst.css">

    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:async';
      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

      void main() {
        initPolymer().run( () {
          Polymer.onReady.then( (_) {
            new Future( () {
                // stuff goes here!
              });
            });
          });
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>A Test</h1>
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To generate stand-alone JavaScript I run dart2js via the command line:

```
pub build --mode=debug
```

And these are the results:

- Dartium (37.0.2062.120 (292122) via Dart Editor 1.7.2) - OK
- Run as JavaScript on Chrome (38.0.2125.111 m) - OK
- Run as JavaScript on Firefox (33.0.3) - OK
- dart2js and run on Chrome - no shadow DOM.
- dart2js and run on Firefox - OK

When it fails the click counter is rendered (invisibly) as

```
<click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
```

This Chrome problem matters because the standard web host on Android is Chrome.

For brevity, I have embedded the Dart script in the HTML. I get the same results when I use a separate .dart file.

Perhaps I have overlooked something - it wouldn't be the first time...

Comment: What version of Chrome did you try?

Comment: The standalone Chrome version is "38.0.2125.111 m"

Comment: I have just tried "pub build --mode=release" and that generated JavaScript that worked fine in Chrome. A bit tricky for debugging, but it's something. I hope it's a clue..

Comment: I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com